# Display Settings.bundle Root.plist in a view inside the app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, settings, settings.bundle

I would like to let the user access the settings for the app both from iOS Settings app and from the app itself.

Right now **I am using Settings.bundle** to access the settings from the Settings app, is there an easy way to implement a controller inside the app to access the same settings?

**As a side question**, is there an easy way to implement a settings-like view starting from a plist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few Open Source projects to do just this. About a year ago I evaluated all the ones I could find and ended up using [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit). Second place was [mySettings](https://bitbucket.org/karemorstol/mysettings/wiki/Home), but it looks as though that is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Just itegrated InAppSettingsKit. Works great.